# JqGrid send serialized form data

Tags: jqgrid

I would like to send serialized form data to jqGrid for posting. Currently I am using the following properties below, but I get no error and the mvc action on the server side is never being reached. It would be really difficult to send a js object into postData as my serialized data contains many array elements.

```
url: lUrl + pParams,
postData: $(myForm).serialize(),
datatype: 'json',
mtype: 'POST'
```

Comment: First of all, please include in all your questions the information about the version and the fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7), which you use. Seconds an example of your data and the signature the MVC action would be very helpful to understand your problem. In general one can use `$.serializeArray` instead of `$.serialize` and modify the data in any way. One can use `serializeGridData` to send the data in the form, which you need.

Comment: I am using jqGrid 4.3. One thing I noticed is that when I switch my mvc action to HttpGet from HttpPost it hits my action, but the parameters do not come in. When I go back to HttpPost on the action fiddler says the action cannot be found. My viewmodel looks like this:`public List<string> SelectedFuturesChainNames{ get; set; }
        public List<string> SelectedAssetClasses { get; set; }
        public List<string> SelectedSectors { get; set; }
        public List<string> SelectedRootSymbols { get; set; }`

Comment: Version 4.3 is really retro version of jqGrid. I recommend you to upgrade to [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.12.1 or to the latest code from GitHub. Please post all information about the problem in the text of your question (click "edit" below the text) instead of comments. It's really difficult to read the code from comments. The problem with Get could depend from version of MVC which you use and from how you return the data. One should use `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` parameter (like `return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`).

Comment: Sorry, all what you send still don't contains enough information about your problem. `lUrl + pParams` is still unknown, The value of `$(myForm).serialize()` is unknown, The parameters of controller action, which you call, is unknown too. It's unclear which MVC you use and the relation of `SelectedFuturesChainNames`, `SelectedAssetClasses`, ... to the parameters of your action method and the format of returned data are unknown. You should describe more clear what you do if you want that other help you. To be able to help one have to understand the problem first of all. Sorry.